# Not drawing bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

```
GIF::GIF(Bitmap* bit, HDC hdc) {
this->bit = bit;
}
void GIF::draw(Graphics* g,HDC hdc, Bitmap *bit)
{
    
    this->position.x = 50;
    this->position.y = 50;
    this->CachedBitmap = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(this->bit, hdc);
    g->DrawCachedBitmap(CachedBitmap.get(), position.x, position.y);
    
}

std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(Bitmap* 

originalBitmap, HDC hdc)
{

    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    return std::make_shared<CachedBitmap>(originalBitmap, 
     &graphics);
}
```

paint:

```
splash->draw(gt, hdc,new Bitmap(L"resoureses/Sample.gif"));
```

if I pass the value to this->bit when creating an instance of the class, and I pass it to the function and draw, then nothing works, and if I use a variable from GIF::Draw(Bitmap* bit), then everything works fine

init.

Main.h:

```
std::shared_ptr<CachedBitmap> CachedBitmap;
GIF* splash;
```

1st variant

```
void loadResources()
{
   Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(L"resoureses/Sample.gif");
   splash = new GIF(bitmap, hdc);
}
void Paint(HDC hdc)
{

    Graphics* gt = new Graphics(hdc);
    splash->draw(gt, hdc);

}
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    Paint(hdc);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
}
 WndProc(){
    hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, Wcc.lpszClassName, nullptr, WS_POPUP | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, x, y,
        windowW, windowH, hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hParent, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);

    loadResources(hwnd );
}
```

2nd variant

```
void loadResources()
{
   Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(L"resoureses/Sample.gif");
   splash = new GIF(bitmap, hdc);
}
void Paint(HDC hdc)
{

    Graphics* gt = new Graphics(hdc);
    splash->draw(gt, hdc,new Bitmap(L"resoureses/Sample.gif"));

}
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    Paint(hdc);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
}
 WndProc(){
    hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, Wcc.lpszClassName, nullptr, WS_POPUP | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, x, y,
        windowW, windowH, hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hParent, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);

    loadResources(hwnd );
}
```

Comment: You probably do not initialize correctly your class, or the content of the class gets destroyed before using it. Please provide the exact implementation of both variants of code, the working one and not working one. Otherwise there is no possibility to guess.

Comment: Passing the address of a local variable into `make_shared`, and then returning it isn't going to work. Did your compiler not warn about this?

Comment: @IInspectable, no. what can then be replaced with make_shared?

Comment: @armagedescu, `Bitmap* bitmap = new Bitmap(L"resoureses/Sample.gif");
splash = new GIF(bitmap, hdc);`

Comment: @IInspectable, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createbitmap

this example not working for me too

Comment: @Y0MMY "Please provide the exact implementation of both variants of code" means you have to provide them, not just a meaningless line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line is causing the problem

```cpp
   this->CachedBitmap = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(this->bit, hdc);
```

This function GIF::draw is called repeatedly whenever windows have to be redrawn. So, when you assign a CachedBitmap first time with `this->bit` it should be ok. But as it is shared pointer, when you do it the second time, the stored CachedBitmap releases the pointer `this->bit` and it gets unusable before reassigning the `shared_ptr` newly returned by `createCachedBitmap`.
Instead, when you pass each time a `new Bitmap` before calling GIF::draw, you allocate new Bitmap so is no problem if you lose the old Bitmap

```cpp
void GIF::draw(Graphics* g,HDC hdc, Bitmap *bit)
{
....
    this->CachedBitmap = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(bit, hdc);
```

My suggestion is to assign `this->CachedBitmap` only once. For instance verify in GIF::draw if it is initialized, and if not assign, if yes do not assign. Or, do it outside draw function, in a place where you know it will be called only once.

Comment: i need all time set new cache, ill change `SelectActiveFrame()`. So what can help me?
I sure problem with `PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap()`,maybe I need to return something besides  `std::make_shared`, but what?

Comment: @Y0MMY If so, then usage of ```this->bit``` does not make sense. You didn't formulate the question to reflect correctly your problem. And I still do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need to copy the **Bitmap** to the local variable **this->bit** in the instance of the class to use it in the **Draw method**, because I'm making a gif player, and every time **Draw** will be called to change the frame

Comment: @Y0MMY I understand your reasoning behind what you are trying to do. But what you are trying to do is not really what you want to do. And your reasoning is not yet a valid reason. What you really need to do, is to load each frame of your ```.gif``` file in a new pointer. So, keep an array of frames, means an array of pointers, preloaded before you make any draw operation. Then on you draw operation access by index the next gif frame from array and draw it.

Comment: I was thinking about this method, but what if there are a lot of gifs? Then you will have to spend more RAM resources

Comment: and anyway i want to get right way to solve my problem

Comment: @Y0MMY do it first for one GIF. Then do real research how many GIFs you can display simultaneously on your window by using this approach. Instead of "thinking about" I expected something like "I tried it myself, done it in my part of research and this is the limit of how many GIFs I can display in one windows simultaneously without causing problems with RAM".

Comment: @Y0MMY "and anyway" about your question: "Not drawing bitmap". I diagnosed and answered it. If you have other questions, please consider discussing them in separate posts. Check the right way to ask questions on stackoverflow, and not only.